# I am making find and replace function for notepad

Tags: c#

I want to select the text on the main form which is written in the find and replace form

```
private void findToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Find f = new Find();

    f.Show();
}

public void find()
{
    int idx = 0;

    while ((idx = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(Text)) != -1)
    {
        textBox1.Select(idx, Text.Length);
    }

}
```

on form 2

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
f.Text = textBox1.Text;
f.find();
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking. Please try to elaborate

Comment: What you're doing it assign the text on texbox1 on form2 to the text of form1, then run a function that looks for a text in the textbox1 of form1, your problem is that textbox1 from form1 and textbox1 from form2 are not the same, unfortunately, you need further guidance that goes to the basics of Windows Forms, and most likely programming in general.

Comment: i am just trying to create a find and replace method in a notepad.
i have designed notepad but i am bot able to do this function find and replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to work, based on what you provided.

Here is something that might help:

```
private void findToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Find f = new Find();
    f.Parent = this; // find a way to pass the Parent to your Find form.
    f.Show();
}

public void find(string findValue)
{
    int idx = 0;

    if ((idx = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(findValue)) != -1)
    {
        textBox1.Select(idx, findValue.Length);
    }

}
```

on form 2

```
Form1 f = (Form1)this.Parent;
f.find(textBox1.Text);
```

You can't instanciate a new Form1, or you will never get your results.

Comment: +1 for refactoring the `find` method to inject the search value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the instance of `Form1` into `Form2` on construction of `Form2`:

```
var f2 = new Form2(this);
f2.Show();
```

Now, store that instance as a `private` field in `Form2`:

```
private Form1 _f1;
```

and in the `.ctor` of `Form2`:

```
public Form2(Form1 f1)
{
    _f1 = f1;
}
```

(**NOTE:** leave the default constructor in place.)

and then when you want to do a `find`:

```
_f1.Text = textBox1.Text;
_f1.find();
```

What you're doing right now is building *another instance* of `Form1`.

One item of interest is `_f1.Text = ...` - I'm guessing that should actually be a text box on `Form1`. You can fix that by making that text box, on `Form1`, `public` in the `Properties` window and then doing something like this instead:

```
_f1.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: On the last part, from what I understand of the question, he wants to create some sort of Find feature. That is, select in form1 what he types in form2. I assume he has a public Text property in Form1 that he uses in the find() method. It would probably be better to pass it as a parameter to the find method though.

Comment: @Charlie, well the `Text` property is suspicious because it would be overriding the title of the `Form`--and as you can see below I +1'd jp2code's answer for the very reason of refactoring the `find` method so I don't necessarily disagree.

Comment: you're right, I forgot that a `Form` had already a `Text` Property